# Finding the remaining angle in this triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

By chance I came across a question on another stackexchange site that involved finding all angles in a triangle. It was actually about drawing the triangle using a computer program, but since I need practice in solving triangle problems anyway, I thought I give it a go. The triangle given is:

[image]

*([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406145/draw-isosceles-triangle-with-angles-and-stuff-in-tikz))*

I managed to find:

- $\alpha = 60°$
- $\beta = 75°$
- $\angle ADC = 15°$
- $\angle BFC = 45°$

Now, the only angle remaining is $\gamma$, but I can't figure out how to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
Since $DE$ and $DF$ are both radii of the circle, then $\Delta DEF$ is isosceles.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that, thanks for the hint! That is the remaining puzzle piece. :-)

Comment: @Max If you're interested in triangles and other angles in a circle, [BBC Bitesize](https://www.bbc.co.uk/education/guides/zcsgdxs/revision) has many of the circle theorems along with their proofs.